# basic chat system on perl under linux

Tags: linux, perl, chat

Im trying to write some basic chat system just to learn perl. Im trying to get the chatlog into a 1 file and print new message if it's appears in the `chatlog.dat` file, So i've wrote a function that does almost the same thing, but I have got some problems and don't know how to solve them.
So now I have 2 problems!

1. I could not understand how to keep `checkFile` function always active (like multiprocession) to continuously check for new messages
2. This problem occurs when I'm trying to write a new message that will be appended into the chatlog. The Interpreter waits for my input on the line `my $newMessage = <STDIN>;`, but, what if someone writes a new message? it will not be shown until he press enter... how to void that?

   ```
   my ($sec,$min,$hour) = localtime();
   while(1){
       my $userMessage = <STDIN>;
       last if $userMessage eq "::quit";
       `echo "($hour:$min:$sec): $userMessage" >>chatlog.dat`;
   }

   sub checkFile{
       my $lastMessage = "";
       my $newMessage = "";
       while (1) {
           my $context = `cat chatlog.dat`;
           split(/\n/, $context);
           $newMessage = $_[$#_];
           if ($newMessage ne $lastMessage) {
               print $newMessage;
               $lastMessage = $newMessage;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: That's what `select` loops are for. Made easier using IO::Select, but still extremely complicated. Simpler using threads.

Comment: You're also building in a race condition of sorts - if you send two messages in close succession, you'll only print the second one.

Comment: @Sobrique yeah that's the 3rd problem but it does not have high priority YET, atleast i can add time option into the chatlog so newly printed message would have another time, thus it will be considered as a NEW message

Comment: If you're writing a program to help you learn perl, you might be better starting with something a bit less complicated...

Comment: @ialarmedalien I'm not a beginner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

```
sub checkFile{
    my $lastMessage = "";
    my $newMessage = "";
    my $userName = $_[0];
    while (1) {
        my $context = `cat chatlog.dat`;
        split(/\n/, $context);
        $newMessage = $_[$#_];
        if ($newMessage ne $lastMessage) {
            $newMessage =~ /^\(.+\):\((.+)\) (.+$)/;
            if ($1 ne $userName) { print "[$1]: $2";}
            $lastMessage = $newMessage;
        }
    }
}

my $userName = "Rocker";
my ($sec,$min,$hour) = localtime();
my $thr = threads -> create ( \&checkFile, $userName ); #Starting a thread to continuously check for the file update

while (1) {
    my $userMessage = <STDIN>; #STDIN will not interfere file checking
    last if $userMessage eq "::quit";
    `echo "($hour:$min:$sec):($userName) $userMessage" >>chatlog.dat` if $userMessage =~ /\S+/;
}

$thr -> join();
```

Comment: Argh! Don't do that. A busy wait loop is a horrible thing to do. It will eat all the IO and CPU your box has to offer, because it's rerunning `cat` just as fast as it can. At least put a `sleep 1;` in there.

Answer (score 1):

First:

- don't use `echo` within a perl script. It's nasty to shell escape when you've got perfectly good IO routines.
- using `cat` to read files is about as nasty as using 'echo'.
- reading `<STDIN>` like that will be a blocking call - which means your script will pause.
- but that's not as bad as it sounds, because otherwise you're running a 'busy wait' loop which'll repeatedy `cat` the file. This is a very bad idea.
- You're assuming writing a file like that is an atomic operation, when it's not. You'll hit problems with doing that too.

What I would suggest you do it look at `IO::Handle` and also consider using `flock` to ensure you've got the file locked for IO. You may also wish to consider `File::Tail` instead.

I would actually suggest though, you want to consider a different mode of IPC - as 'file swapping' is quite inefficient. If you really want to use the filesystem for your IO, you might want to consider using a FIFO pipe - have each 'client' open it's own, and have a server reading and coalescing them.

Either way though - you'll either need to use `IO::Select` or perhaps multithreading, just to swap back and forth between reading and writing. http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html

Comment: IO::Select won't work with File::Tail, since File::Tail doesn't provide a system file handle but a "virtual" one only known to Perl.

Comment: Ah, fair point - I was thinking more in terms of using `can_read` on `STDIN`.

Comment: I'm gonna modify the main code based on your feedback, thank you